# ActivityOptionsCompat not working in android 2.3

Tags: android, android-support-library

I have implemented window animations using ActivityOptionsCompat and ActivityCompat which is recently supported in android support-v4 library.

I have used below code for implement animation:

```
Intent subActivity = new Intent(WindowAnimations.this,
                    AnimatedSubActivity.class);
            // The enter/exit animations for the two activities are
            // specified by xml resources
            Bundle translateBundle = ActivityOptionsCompat
                    .makeCustomAnimation(WindowAnimations.this,
                            R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_left)
                    .toBundle();
            ActivityCompat.startActivity(WindowAnimations.this,
                        subActivity, translateBundle);
```

Above code is working fine in android 4.3 and 4.0.

Anybody able to make it work in 2.X?Any help is appreciated.

Comment: From the docs of the `startActivity()` method: *When run on versions of the platform where this feature does not exist the activity will be launched normally.*.

Comment: Thanks for your quick comment.But as I can see in ActivityCompat docs http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat.html I cant find anything described such description there.Also I think as it is given in support v-4 lib to support that animation in older version from API level 4.Can you please give your thoughts on it?

Comment: The documentation that I quoted is for the `startActivity()` method that takes 3 parameters(Activity, Intent, Bundle). I haven't worked with that compatibility class but it could be reasonable to assume that the animations might not be possible on lower versions(due to limitation on the system itself). That class might also be introduced in the compatibility package so you can still make use of the animations when possible(falling back to the default on lower versions) so the developer doesn't have to implement the API based logic.

Comment: From my past experience with support package,they are provided to support same feature in backward OS devices.At current point of time,I dont think they had provided that apis in support package,to provide those animations only in some of devices and if it is than they might have mentioned in documentation somewhere which I cant find till.

Comment: It's your right to assume. *and if it is than they might have mentioned in documentation somewhere which I cant find till.* - I've put that in the first comment(that line it's taken from the docs so I don't know what do you expect more than this).

Comment: can you please provide me link of android doc from where you are referencing your first comment for same method?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

@Luksprog basically already answered this in the first on your question, but here's some more documentation to further support that claim.

First, read the the javadoc for [`ActivityCompat#startActivity(Activity activity, Intent intent, Bundle options)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat.html#startActivity%28android.app.Activity,%20android.content.Intent,%20android.os.Bundle%29) *carefully*. I've highlighted some relevant keywords:

> Start an activity with additional launch information, **if able**.
>
> In Android 4.1+ additional options were introduced to allow for more
>   control on activity launch animations. Applications can use this
>   method along with ActivityOptionsCompat to use these animations when
>   available. **When run on versions of the platform where this feature
>   does not exist the activity will be launched normally**.

So that basically tells us that the (optional) animations feature will only work on versions of Android that natively support it. On all other platform versions, the `Activity` will be launched 'normally' - that is, without the optional animation.

The actual proof can easily be found in the [source code of `ActivityCompat`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.3_r2.1/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat.java#86):

```
public static void startActivity(Activity activity, Intent intent, Bundle options) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {
        ActivityCompatJB.startActivity(activity, intent, options);
    } else {
        activity.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

In other words: if this code is executed on a pre-JB device, a plain old `startActivity()` call will be mad, where the `options` parameter gets ignored. Only JB devices will end up using that.

Perhaps redundant to mention, but obviously the same applies to the `startActivityForResult()` counterpart.

To summarize: Currently the Support Library simply offers a static helper class to execute certain functionality in *"a backwards compatible fashion"* - it doesn't actually backport that functionality (yet). All it does at this stage is save you having to write the `if/else` condition in your own app.

That being said, the current implementation does allow for a future backport of the actual functionality. That's possibly also why the `ActivityOptionsCompat` class exists. Right now the class provides an 'empty' implementation for pre-JB devices, which, in theory, could be 'filled' at a later stage. Any code calling through these compatibility helpers will then automagically start working.

[Example of an `ActivityOptionsCompat` call](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.3_r2.1/android/support/v4/app/ActivityOptionsCompat.java#43) returning an empty implementation:

```
public static ActivityOptionsCompat makeCustomAnimation(Context context,
        int enterResId, int exitResId) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {
        return new ActivityOptionsImplJB(
            ActivityOptionsCompatJB.makeCustomAnimation(context, enterResId, exitResId));
    }
    return new ActivityOptionsCompat();
}
```